# How to concat all values from a row into a single varchar in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if there is a way to concatenate all fields in a row, in a single NVARCHAR field.

Say, if I have a table like this:

```
FieldA             FieldB                FieldC
---------------------------------------------------------
Abc                 Bcd                    123
Cde                 Def                    234
                        ...
```

Is there a way to get either a table with a single column, with the concatenated values, like:

```
Field       
-------------
AbcBcd123
CdeDef234
  ...
```

Or this same operation but for a single row?, and then I could just iterate over the rows some other way and do the operation on each row separately.

The number of fields in this table is always variable, it could be three, like in this example, or all the way to around 100 columns, that's why I don't do something like simply:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(t.FieldA, t.FieldB, t.FieldC)
FROM
    TestTable t
```

Comment: FYI, rows have columns, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It will work for any table with any number of columns. It just needs a primary key column.

It is based on XML and XQuery. No need for any dynamic SQL.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ColA VARCHAR(10), ColB CHAR(3), ColC INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (ColA, ColB, ColC) VALUES
('Abc', 'Bcd', 123),
('Cde', 'Def', 234);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT p.*
    , result = c.query('/root/*[not(local-name()="ID")]/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @tbl AS p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @tbl AS c WHERE p.ID = c.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+------+------+-----------+
| ID | ColA | ColB | ColC |  result   |
+----+------+------+------+-----------+
|  1 | Abc  | Bcd  |  123 | AbcBcd123 |
|  2 | Cde  | Def  |  234 | CdeDef234 |
+----+------+------+------+-----------+
```